# ¿Cómo concatenar cadenas en tiempo real con Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Este es mi código para generar el ID con las dos primeras letras del primer nombre y las dos letras del primer apellido mas la edad, ese seria el id, pero todo esto lo quiero mosrar en un campo para ver el id en tiempo real generada.
Trate de hacerlo así pero no jala. :/

JavasCript

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function generarId(){
caja=document.forms["id"].elements;

var numero1 = Text(caja["numero1"].value);
var numero2 = Text(caja["numero2"].value);
var numero3 = Number(caja["numero3"].value);

var no2 =numero1.substr(0,2);
var ap =numero2.substr(0,2);


resultado2=no2+ap;

if(!isNaN(resultado2)){
 caja["resultado2"].value=no2+ap+numero3;
   }
  }
 </script>
```

Este es mi form en HTML

```
       <form method="post" name="id">

 Nombre: <input type="text" name="numero1" size="10" onKeyUp="generarId()"/>
 Apellidos: <input type="text" name="numero2" size="10" onKeyUp="generarId()"/>
Edad:  <input type="text" name="numero3" size="10" onKeyUp="generarId()"/>


Resultado: <input type="text" name="resultado2"/>

</form>
```

Comment: `text?` para que lo utiliza? es un función definida por usted? no conozco un `cast` como este, intente eliminar esto dado que `value` ya retorna un _String_ (texto), tener cuidado que al realizar el `cast` a `Number` tomará un valor por defecto 0 cuando el `input` esté vacío y en la concatenación añadirá un 0 :)

Comment: Era Text, para indicar que el campo es tipo texto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function generarId(){
    caja=document.forms["id"].elements;

    var numero1 = caja["numero1"].value;
    var numero2 = caja["numero2"].value;
    var numero3 = Number(caja["numero3"].value);

    var no2 =numero1.substr(0,2);
    var ap =numero2.substr(0,2);


    var resultado2=no2+ap;
    document.getElementById("resultado2").value=no2+ap+numero3;
}
```

Por ahi podes usar un método mas efectivo, como seleccionar los inputs por su id

```
 <form method="post" name="id">

 Nombre: <input type="text" name="numero1" id="numero1" size="10" onKeyUp="generarId()"/>
 Apellidos: <input type="text" name="numero2" id="numero2" size="10" onKeyUp="generarId()"/>
Edad:  <input type="text" name="numero3" id="numero3" size="10" onKeyUp="generarId()"/>


Resultado: <input type="text" name="resultado2" id="resultado2"/>

</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function generarId(){
        document.getElementById("resultado2").value =
            document.getElementById("numero1").value.substr(0,2) +
            document.getElementById("numero2").value.substr(0,2) +
            ( Number(document.getElementById("numero3").value) || '');
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: Excelente justo lo que estaba buscando muchísimas gracias.

Comment: @ManueelPerezz no te olvides de marcar mi respuesta como correcta, si es el caso. Gracias!